# Pydantic to gRPC

Tags: python, grpc, fastapi, openapi, pydantic

We want to implement the following architecture:

The model will be defined per service as PyDantic model, using their validation infrastructure.

Then of this model we want to generate gRPC (pb2) to communicate between services (internal).

Then we will have one service called "api-gateway" which will be implemented in FastAPI, and will include the endpoints that we are exposing to the public. This endpoints will have the OpenAPI decorators using FastApi infrastructure.
The implementation of the endpoints will be a relevant gRPC call to the service.

This allows us to:

1. Keep one source of truth for validation & modeling
2. Generate inter communication
3. Generate public documentation and have a good control of what we are exposing

To make it work we need to:

In the micro service level use FastAPI so it will generate a json schema of our functionality -> convert this to proto using openapi-generator (java) -> use grpc_tools.protoc to generate the clients (python)

This is obviously ugly.
As the source PyDantic is a schematic language and I already have the interface.
FastAPI is used only for openAPI generation and not for HTTP (in the micro services)
Too many conversions.

**Does anyone knows a way to convert pedantic to a gRPC communication?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursive Pydantic model to gRPC protobuf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75899510/recursive-pydantic-model-to-grpc-protobuf)

Comment: Yes and no, this is not my issue.
I am leaning towards skipping protobuf like google did here with Java
https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-with-json/

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps post more details in your Q describing your issue + intended solution and others can weigh in?