# Recursive Pydantic model to gRPC protobuf

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc, pydantic

Is it possible to convert recursive pydantic model to protobuf and send it through gRPC?

Example:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel

class RowGroup(BaseModel):
    report_code: Optional[str]
    tab: Optional[str]
    parent: Optional[RowGroup]
    nested_row_groups: Optional[list[RowGroup]]
```

Proto message:

```
message RowGroup {
    string report_code = 1;
    string tab = 2;
    RowGroup parent = 3;
    repeated RowGroup nested_row_groups = 4;
}
```

Filling data:

```py
def get_recursion_scenario() -> RowGroup:
    a = RowGroup(report_code='a', tab='a tab', nested_row_groups=None, parent=None)
    b = RowGroup(report_code='b', tab='b tab', parent=a, nested_row_groups=None)
    c = RowGroup(report_code='c', tab='c tab', parent=a, nested_row_groups=None)
    a.nested_row_groups = [b, c]
    return a
```

If I try convert like this, my program fails from recursion depth limit:

```py
def to_proto(pydantic_a):
    if pydantic_a is None:
        return None
    grpc_model = fill_row_groups_pb2.RowGroup(
        tab=pydantic_a.tab,
        report_code=pydantic_a.report_code,
        parent=to_proto(pydantic_a.parent),
        nested_row_groups=list(to_proto(i) for i in pydantic_a.nested_row_groups)
    )
    return grpc_model
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue here is the resolution of the `parent` attribute on the child nodes.

**Model `a` has 2 children (e.g. `nested_row_groups`), `b` and `c`:**

```
  a
 / \
b   c
```

**The following infinite cycle is observed:**

When instantiating your object `RowGroup(a)`:

- `a` has 2 children `nested_row_groups`: `[b, c]`
- Instantiate `RowGroup(b)` and add to `a.nested_row_groups`:

  - `b` has a `parent`: `a`

    - Instantiate `RowGroup(a)` and add to `b.parent`

Thus `RowGroup(a)` depends on `RowGroup(a)` and you will recurse infinitely.

### Possible solutions:

A few possible ways you can solve this:

#### 1. Store `parent` as an `id` instead of an object:

If the `parent` attribute was an id, instead of an entire object, you wouldn't have infinite recursion. This would require changes to your protobuf definition as well as pydantic models.

#### 2. Unlink `RowGroup` references:

Create a `RowItem` object without references, then create a `RowGroup` object linking the two: *(I recommend doing this...)*

**Proto:**

```
message RowItem {
    string report_code = 1;
    string tab = 2;
}

message RowGroup {
    RowItem item = 1;
    RowItem parent = 3;
    repeated RowGroup nested_row_groups = 4;
}
```

Your pydantic models would look like:

```py
class RowItem(BaseModel):
    report_code: Optional[str]
    tab: Optional[str]

class RowGroup(BaseModel):
    item: RowItem
    parent: Optional[RowItem]
    nested_row_groups: Optional[list[RowGroup]]
```

Functional code:

```py
def get_recursion_scenario() -> RowGroup:
    a = RowGroup(
            item=RowItem(report_code='a', tab='a tab')
        )
    b = RowGroup(
            item=RowItem(report_code='b', tab='b tab'),
            parent=a
        )
    c = RowGroup(
            item=RowItem(report_code='c', tab='c tab'),
            parent=a
        )
    a.nested_row_groups = [b, c]
    return a
```